# Javascript promise and object context

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

I have a problem when it comes to create an object in javascript inside a promise chain. For some reason it gets all messed up and my attributtes are not showing correctly:

```
var historyManager = new HistoryManager();
var examManager = new ExamManager();
var recipeManager = new RecipeManager();
var historiaObj = {
    obs : "",
    freR : "",
    exams : [],
    meds : [],
    content : ""
};
var allHistory = Object.create(historiaObj);
return historyManager.refresh(history).then(function (historyRefreshed) {
    history = historyRefreshed;
    allHistory.obs = historyRefreshed.get("obs");
    return examManager.getByHistory(historyRefreshed);
}).then(function (examenFisico) {
    allHistory.freR = examenFisico.get("freR");
    return recipeManager.getByHistory(history)
}).then(function (recipe) {
    allHistory.content = recipe.get("content");
    return recipeManager.getMedsByRecipe(recipe);
}).then(function (meds) {
    for(var i = 0 ; i < meds.length ; i++){
        allHistory.meds.push(meds[i].get("name"))
    }
}).then(function () {
    return allHistory;
});
```

For some reason when I try to check if the meds where added correctly, they are under `_proto_` but not in the main object. How can I fix this, or what is it that I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may also want to have a look at [How do I access previous promise results in a .then() chain?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572). Especially that global `history` variable seems to be problematic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue does not appear to be promise related. The behavior you're seeing is how [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) works:

```
Object.create(proto);
```

`Object.create` is used when you want to create a new object to instantiate with `new`. It doesn't look like you need to use `Object.create` here. Just assign the plain object to `allHistory`.

```
var allHistory = {
    obs : "",
    freR : "",
    exams : [],
    meds : [],
    content : ""
};
```

Comment: It does indeed solve my problem, but this is just a part of my real problem, will this have the same behavior if I want to create and array of allHistory objects? I mean in that case I will have more than one object to create.

Comment: You could do something like `for( var x = 0; x < 10; x++ ) { histories.push({ objs: "" ... }); }` which would create a new object for every array element. Or you could use underscore or a similar library which provide a `clone` function to clone basic vanilla objects.